# Calculate SE of regression coefficients using p-value (for meta-analysis)

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, regression-coefficients, standard-error, meta-analysis

I would like to do a meta-analysis of the regression coefficients from a group of 9 studies, but they authors had not reported the SEs.

For all of the studies, the tables included in the reports only have coefficients with significance stars based on p-values.

Would it be possible to back-calculate (or at least estimate) the standard errors of the coefficients using p-values and df (because the n and obviously number of variables are reported) only?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with that information. You need to backcalculate the value of $t$ corresponding to that $p$ with the relevant degrees of freedom. If you use R then qt(p/2, df) should do it. Then since you know that $t = \frac{\hat \beta}{se}$ you have the standard error.

However
If you only have 0.05, 0.01, 0.001 as the $p$-values that is going to potentially be conservative.

If the original studies used different numbers of covariates then you are not going to be synthesising like with like even if you use the same covariate from each primary study